# ActionFunction doesn't fire

Tags: visualforce-component, actionfunction

I've tried to simplify my problem. I have a component like this:

```
<apex:component controller="GenericLookup">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jquery-1.8.2.min.js')}" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();

        function openLookup(baseURL, width, modified, searchParam) {
            // Intercept Salesforce lookup
            // Pop custom lookup window

            // Detect popup closing
            var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                console.log('Approaching the enemy base.');
                if (curPopupWindow == null || curPopupWindow.closed) {
                    console.log('I\'ve infiltrated the enemy base.');
                    try {
                        window.clearInterval(interval);
                        console.log('Hacking enemy systems.');
                        contactSelected();
                        console.log('Data retrieved. End mission.');
                    }
                    catch (e) { console.log('We\'ve been had! Abort mission!'); }
                }
                console.log('Standby.');
           }, 1000);
        }
    </script>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!ContactSelected}" name="contactSelected" reRender="" />
    <apex:outputLink onclick="openLookup(params);" />
</apex:component>
```

And my controller is something like this:

```
public class GenericLookup {
    public void ContactSelected() {
        System.debug('Callback has this: ' + this);
    }
}
```

When I debug the page I see all my console.log calls in the component. I do not see the System.debug in the controller. The browser (Chrome) developer tools have no errors.

Why is my ActionFunction doing nothing? How can I fix it?

Comment: Silly question on my part: Are you sure your debug flags in the Developer Console or Debug Logs setting set high enough to see your debug statements? I make this mistake about weekly, which is why I ask.

Comment: Is there an`<apex:form/>` tag anywhere? `<apex:actionFunction/>` must be a child of that tag.

Comment: Didn't think of that as an issue. I don't think that's the case. The popup window calls System.debug, and I see that call just fine. And yes, I see all the javascript console.log calls.

Comment: Not sure if `rerender=""` will actually call the controller. Does the page refresh? If so, then try putting any text inside the rerender like `rerender="nothing"`.  Also do check that the debug log settings are at a minimum of DEBUG

Comment: I believe `reRender=""` works, though I actually have `reRender="dummy"` in my code. How can I check the log settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I gave you enough information, but it turns out there was more to it. I also had this tag in the component backed by an ID property:

```
<apex:inputHidden id="__lkid" value="{!NewID}" />
```

Bad idea. `NewID` is initially null, but on postbacks this hidden input manages to set it to a blank ID. That setter triggers another property to get the object, but of course the object didn't exist, so things broke down. That's why none of my functions were firing: things had already failed in the properties' setup. I modified the property:

```
public ID NewID {
    get;
    set {
        try {
            value.getSObjectType();// This prevents the bad blank value
            NewID = value;
            if (Record.ID != NewID) Record = null;// This resets my other property
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('ID is invalid: ' + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry to waste your guys' time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should terminate the actionFunction tag after outputLink.

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!ContactSelected}" name="contactSelected" reRender="">
    <apex:outputLink onclick="openLookup(params);" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```